# Get values from a variable containing a list

Tags: prolog

So i'm pretty new at Prolog, im making a puzzle solver and i have a predicate with this signature:

`nao_altera_linhas_anteriores(Posicoes, L, Ja_Preenchidas):-`

where Posicoes is a list of line and column, like this:

```
 [(1,2), (2,3), (4,4)])
```

and i dont know how to acess each element of the list using the name Posicoes, i also want to acess each line, so in this example i want to acess 1, 2 and 4, does anyone have an idea? I'm just a begginer and i'm having trouble grasping how to use this language in comparison to C or Java.

Comment: Looks like you need to study a Prolog tutorial and focus on unification and list processing. There are plenty of resources online if you search for them.

Answer (score 1):

You "access" each of the [list](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse13) elements with [unification](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5).

When your predicate is defined as:

```
pred([H|T]) :- ...
```

given a goal `pred(Z)`, it will have to unify `Z` with `[H|T]`, so it will succeed if `Z` is a list, with `H` being the first element of that list, and `T` being a list containing the other elements.

You can build more complex terms to unify in the head of your rule:

```
pred([(X,Y)|T], [X|S]) :- pred(T, S).
pred([], []).
```

This will extract the X coordinate from the first list:

```
?- pred([(1,2), (2,3), (4,4)], L).
L = [1, 2, 4].
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with SWI-Prolog:

```
?- Posicoes = [(1,2), (2,3), (4,4)], nth1(3, Posicoes, (Line, _)).
Posicoes = [(1, 2),  (2, 3),  (4, 4)],
Line = 4.
```

You can use this for searching all Lines using:

```
?- nth1(Position, $Posicoes, (Line, _)).
Position = Line, Line = 1,
Position = Line, Line = 2,
Position = 3, Line = 4.
```